# What is wrong with my JPA test case? I cannot remove tuples with em.remove()

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, junit

I am trying to test the delete method of my repository class but I can't pass the test.
Here is my test code.

[post delete test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBm6G.jpg)

When persistAll() is called, members are added to the persistence context. And next, when flush(), 100 posts are added to the persistence context because of the Cascade.Persist option.

And I called count(), delete() and count() again to check whether the post tuple is removed from the database or not.

Here are the count() and delete() codes.

[methods of my repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPufA.jpg)

And I got this failure message from JUnit

[test failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt3BB.jpg)

Comment: I solved it by adding em.clear() after em.flush() in persistAll() method

Comment: So your question is solved? Then please add your comment as the answer

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I'm new to stack overflow. Could you tell me how to add my comment as the answer?

Comment: I understand what you said thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding em.clear() after em.flush() in persistAll() method.